# How to write a list comprehension instead of a nested loop In Python?

Tags: python, loops, list-comprehension

I was dealing with different dataframes in python. The first dataframe named cities looks like this:

```
                         city  Population              NBA
0               New York City    20153634      Knicks Nets
1                 Los Angeles    13310447  Lakers Clippers
2      San Francisco Bay Area     6657982         Warriors
3                     Chicago     9512999    Bulls[note 9]
4           Dallas–Fort Worth     7233323        Mavericks
```

And second dataframe named nba_df look like this:

```
                  team   W   L   W/L%    GB   PS/G   PA/G   SRS  year League
0      Toronto Raptors  59  23  0.720   0.0  111.7  103.9  7.29  2018    NBA
1       Boston Celtics  55  27  0.671   4.0  104.0  100.4  3.23  2018    NBA
2   Philadelphia 76ers  52  30  0.634   7.0  109.8  105.3  4.30  2018    NBA
3  Cleveland Cavaliers  50  32  0.610   9.0  110.9  109.9  0.59  2018    NBA
4       Indiana Pacers  48  34  0.585  11.0  105.6  104.2  1.18  2018    NBA
```

What I am trying to do is to determine where the team is located from teams name. For ex. Philadelphia 76ers are located at Philadelpia. So to do that I wrote a nested loop below:

```
city = []
for i in nba_df['team']:
    added = False
    for j in i.split():
        for k in cities['city']:
            for l in k.split():
                if j == l and added == False:
                    city.append(k)
                    added = True
    if added == False:
        city.append('Not in list')
    
nba_df['city'] = city
```

The loop iterates through the nba_df['team'] and splits the string and iterates for each word over the cities['city'] column which are splitted too, and if a word matches with the other, then the city name will be added into list. Otherwise it will be added as Not in list. I know it has some bugs, what will happen if New York City is being iterated before just saying as an example New Orleans? Than it will append the New York City to the list and skip the rest of it. So it might append wrong cities. Anyways code does what I want but I wanted to write it in list comprehension. Because it looks amateur to me.
I tried something like this:

```
city = [k if j == l for l in k.split() in [k for k in cities['city'] in [j for j in i.split() in [i for i in nba_df['team']]]]]
```

But of course it didn't work. It raised and sytanx error pointing on `l for l` which is at the beginning.
What I am asking for you is to review my loop and I wonder how would you rewrite it? List comprehension or another way. How would you approach to the problem?
Thank you.

Comment: Please don't. What benefit do you think this achieves? This will get an automated "reject" in any proper code review.

Comment: I already passed the test. I only wonder if there is a better way of it.

Comment: "I only wonder if there is a better way of it" A comprehension is certainly not such a way. If anything, a vectorized, "native" pandas solution will be more readable and much more performant.

Answer (score 1):

You forgot the braces at the first split() in the list comprehention.

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
city = [k if j == l for l in k.split() in [k for k in cities['city'] in [j for j in i.split() in [i for i in nba_df['team']]]]]
```

instead of this:

```
city = [k if j == l for l in k.split in [k for k in cities['city'] in [j for j in i.split() in [i for i in nba_df['team']]]]]
```

Comment: It doesn't matter. Same error. 'invalid syntax'. I edited the question, it seems everyone will think braces are the problem but in fact it is not.

Comment: also check this:
city = [([c for c in cities['city'] if any(word in set(nba_df['team']) for word in c.split())].pop(0) if c == city else c) for city in city]

Comment: No. It didn't work. local variable 'city' referenced before assignment.